# HTML/JS/CSS - how to randomise videos

Tags: html, fivem

I'm a total noob with coding, so I'm probably going about this the wrong way.

For this fiveM server, we currently have an mp4 video running as the background of the loading screen, i want to randomise this with multiple videos created though.

This is the current HTML code we've got, where i've added the source, but I have no clue how to trigger it to randomise - do i need to add an additional JS file? or can i somehow trigger this off the CSS?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Loading</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontstyle.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
    </head>

    <video autoplay muted loop id="video">
        <source src="video/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/bgvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <body style="background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49); overflow: hidden;">

    <body id="page">
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Welcome to City In Motion<br><br><h2><i>Your story begins here...</i></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" style='width:160%;height:345%'></div>
        <div class="sidepanel" id="particles-js" style="background-color: black;"></div>
          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>

    <audio id="music" autoplay loop >
        <source src="music/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>

    <script>
        var music = document.getElementById("music");
        music.volume = 0.02
        window.onload = function(){
        
        document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 32: //SpaceBar
                    music.muted = !music.muted;
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }}
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: definitely will need js for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out - thanks for the assistance though.

```
 <script>

        const VIDEOS = ["Load1.mp4", "Load2.mp4", "Load3.mp4"]

        const randomVideoNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (VIDEOS.length - 1))

        console.log(randomVideoNumber)

        const videoSrcElement = document.getElementById("video-src")

        videoSrcElement.setAttribute("src", "video/" + VIDEOS[randomVideoNumber])
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store all music names in array like ["m1.mp3","m2.mp3"] then on generate a random number n between 0 and music array length then according to generated random number n  pick the song or music from music array using random number as a index e.g musicarray[n]

you can find more useful details here [Useful Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149289/how-to-play-a-random-music-track-on-click)

Comment: Okay, so essentially same principals, but change music to video instead - ill give this a go and let you know how it goes - thanks!

Comment: yeah sure  logic or principle is same.